Interrupt script repeatedly using Application Timer
Dumb Summary: If I wrote the following horrific code and ran it...
import time
import bpy
def blink():
    c = bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient
    t = time.time()
    c.g = t % 1
    return 0.2

bpy.app.timers.register(blink)

...all my 3D viewports would pulse from ~black to green forever. Would there be any way to stop this, other than quitting Blender?
Actual Problem
I find many of Blender's theme colors rather confusing: both the hierarchy and the naming makes little sense. So, instead of going through the User preferences GUI one at a time, changing and breaking a color, I wrote a script to change every color, one at a time, to hot pink, logging the theme name with each. This script uses an Application Timer via bpy.app.timers.register() so that the UI can redraw/react to eacj color change.
My intention was to let the script run until I saw the color I wanted change, and to fire a quick Ctrl+C at that point, and to look at the log to see the name of the color that changed. But that doesn't work. I can't find any way to kill the script after it has been set in motion.
Now, my script is well-behaved and the function eventually returns None and stops...but how could I stop it early?
For the curious, my script for making parts of the UI blink hot pink is:
import bpy
import mathutils

test_color = mathutils.Color((1.0, 0.0, 1.0))
theme_colors = []

def crawl(object, path):
    for name in dir(object):
        if name in ['bl_rna', 'rna_type']:
            continue  # Skip meta-properties that cause infinite loops
        path2 = f'{path}.{name}'
        try:
            value = getattr(object, name)
            if isinstance(value, mathutils.Color):
                theme_colors.append({'path':path2, 'obj':value})
            elif value.__class__.__name__.startswith("Theme"):
                crawl(value, path2)
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(f"Error accessing {path2}, skipping: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unexpected error on {path2}, skipping: {e}")

last_color = None
def modify_next_color():
    global last_color
    if last_color is not None:
         last_color["obj"][:] = last_color["orig"]

    if len(theme_colors)==0:
        print('done!')
        return None

    color = theme_colors.pop(0)
    color_value = color["obj"]
    last_color = {"obj":color_value, "orig":color_value.copy()}

    print(f'{color["path"]} was {color_value}')
    color_value[:] = test_color
    return 0.2

# Find all theme the colors
crawl(bpy.context.preferences.themes[0], 'theme')

# Kick off the party!
bpy.app.timers.register(modify_next_color)


The function should check a global value and quit if it's true,  then you only need to register a hotkey to change that value

Why not use a modal operator ?

you can catch the Ctrl+C in Python (replace the sys.exit(0)). Set the timer interval to None (the 0.2, use a global variable) or just call bpy.app.timers.unregister(blink) to stop it.

@Blunder That's a functionally-valid answer. Note that on macOS it only works if you've launched Blender from the Terminal, and issue the ctrl+c there, not within any area of the Blender UI. Care to make that a full-fledged answer, not a comment?

You can catch the  Ctrl+c (SIGINT, signal interrupt) in Python with a signal handler.
In the handler you can either call bpy.app.timers.unregister(blink) to stop the timer:
import time
import bpy

import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('+++++++++++++ You pressed Ctrl+C! +++++++++++++')
    bpy.app.timers.unregister(blink)     # <--- stop the timer

def blink():
    c = bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient
    t = time.time()
    c.g = t % 1
    return 0.2

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
bpy.app.timers.register(blink)

Or you use a global variable to store the timer interval and set it to None in the signal handler to stop the timer:
import time
import bpy

import signal
import sys

timer_interval = 0.2

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('+++++++++++++ You pressed Ctrl+C! +++++++++++++')
    global timer_interval
    timer_interval = None   # <-- stop the timer

def blink():
    c = bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient
    t = time.time()
    c.g = t % 1
    return timer_interval   # <-- call timer again in x seconds

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
bpy.app.timers.register(blink)

Note that on MacOS and Linux it only works if you've launched Blender from the Terminal ($ ./blender &), and issue the Ctrl+c there, not within any area of the Blender UI.
On Windows you need to toggle the System Console window first if it's not open, then run the script and issue the Ctrl+c there to stop it.
